# Where can I find an overhead view of the Battlefield Back to Karkand maps?

Tags: battlefield-3

Can anyone find an overhead view of B2K maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [this site](http://bf3blog.com/2011/12/back-to-karkand-map-overviews/), which has scans from a Gamestop exclusive strategy guide.

As they're scanned from a document, I can't verify that copyright-wise it would be OK to directly link them here.  If I find another source, I'll try to update this answer with better images/links.

Answer (score 4):

You might try this:

http://randomnade.com/game/battlefield-3/maps

> Our goal is to take competitive gaming, casual or pro, to the next level by improving the way teams and gamers prepare for competition. Strategy building is something every team has done their own way. Randomnade gives gamers a tool to simplify the process of creating, browsing and sharing strategies for the games they play and compete on every day. Next level gaming is not only a motto, but something we push to achieve.

You can not just view the maps but mark them up with strategies to share, etc. It hasn't been updated with the B2K maps yet but I'm sure it will be.